# IP warm up and leverage on previous email send system

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, ip-warming

my new client is sending emails from a specific website and is planning to move to marketing cloud.
He might send in future around 1M emails per month.
Can we leverage on the previous IP that was already sending emails? If so how?
In the other case shall we warm our IP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reuse/migrate an IP address to Marketing Cloud, and should focus on IP warmup instead. You will need to split your sends between the old system in  place today, and Marketing Cloud, as safely reaching 1 million monthly emails will take at least 6-8 weeks.

I have written an article on IP warming here, where I put forward suggested volumes and warmup duration: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/email-deliverability-ip-warmup-lukas-lunow/

Comment: thanks lukas, I'll read it now; what if I use the very same same sender email/address? Do I need to warm up anyway?

Comment: Yes, the reputation is in 90% related to the IP address, the sender domain has little impact here.

Comment: Pls shall I warm up my ip even if I dont buy a SAP (and a private IP)?

Comment: No, if you use a shared IP, then warmup is not essential. But: You will not be allowed to have such big volumes on a shared IP. Generally speaking: 0-100k month: shared IP, 100-250k: free to choose, above 250k: always private IP.

Comment: thanks Lukas, can I start with shared IP and then buy a private one?

Comment: That is correct, @eeadev - please refer to [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318527&type=1) for more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131699/discussion-between-lukas-lunow-and-eeadev).